# CSS div disappears before I'm able to execute the click event

Tags: css

I have the following CSS code:

```
#searchbar-wrapper input#header-searchbar:focus + 
    #search-dropdown-wrapper { display: block; }
```

The purpose is that a dropdown becomes visible when the user puts focus on a textbox.
The dropdown should by default be invisible though:

```
#searchbar-wrapper #search-dropdown-wrapper{ display: none; }
```

Now the problem is that when I try to select an item from the dropdown list (anchor href), the dropdown wrapper disappears before I'm actually able to execute the click event. This happens because there is no focus on the textbox anymore.

Is there an easy solution for my problem without requiring to change the entire code?

Thanks!

Edit: I've added the resulting HTML in an image, because it is being dynamically generated.

[image]

Edit2: Fiddle based on the fiddle made by @anpsmn: http://jsfiddle.net/thh9z99c/2/
I need a list with anchors because they represent a list with urls.

Comment: Can you post related html code?

Comment: because when you select an item, the `focus` is no longer on the text box.

Comment: I know, just looking for a quick and easy solution. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How about this? `#searchbar-wrapper input#header-searchbar:focus +     #search-dropdown-wrapper, #searchbar-wrapper input#header-searchbar + #search-dropdown-wrapper:focus { display: block; } `

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work unfortunately...

Comment: how about a blanket statement? 

`#searchbar-wrapper input#header-searchbar:focus + #search-dropdown-wrapper,
#search-dropdown-wrapper:focus,
#search-dropdown-wrapper *:focus {
    display: block;
}`

Comment: It would really be easier if you make a quick mockup in jsfiddle or something... It's hard seeing how your markup really looks like and playing around with it to try some approaches...

Comment: @KimGysen Aah, It works if the dropdown is a select. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/thh9z99c/1/)

Comment: @anpsmn Thanks for the fiddle. I added it to my question details. I need the ul with anchors though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS pseudo selector [:focus] and then extend it to the child element.

//CSS BLOCK

```
#searchbar-wrapper input#header-searchbar{

}
a{
  display: none;
}
#searchbar-wrapper input#header-searchbar:focus>a { // use [:focus>a] 
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't test this, but I found that it worked with the pseudo element active instead of focus. If you can create a fiddle to indicate that it works, I will accept it.

Comment: Yea no problem, I don't know what the rest of your css looks like so it would be hard for me to give you the exact answer your looking for unless you want to put it up on a fiddle. I have it working this way on my own site's header for the dropdown https://codingstock.com you can find the css here https://codingstock.com/css/header.css

Answer (score 0):

It works with the pseudo-class active instead of focus:

```
#searchbar-wrapper input#header-searchbar:focus + 
#search-dropdown-wrapper, #searchbar-wrapper input#header-searchbar + 
#search-dropdown-wrapper:active { display: block; } 
#searchbar-wrapper #search-dropdown-wrapper{ display: none; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thh9z99c/3/